# How to found if a TFS workspace is a local or server workspace

Tags: powershell, command-line, version-control, tfs

Is there a way to find out if a specific folder mapped in an existing tfs workspace is a [local workspace or a server workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx)?

I'm mostly interested by an answer using the `tf.exe` command or `powershell` or even api (but not with the GUI!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search (hours and hours in the very bad msdn documentation about the `tf.exe` command!), I have found the way to get the information!

First you have to use the `tf.exe workfold c:\your\path` command to find out in which workspace the folder is. The command output something like that:

```
================================================================
Workspace : NameOfYourWorkspace (John Doe)
Collection: https://tfs.yourtfs.com/tfs/defaultcollection
 $/: C:\your\path
```

Then you have to extract the 'workspace' (note: we really don't know why here the `tf.exe` command don't output the workspace in the format accepted everywhere by the `tf.exe` command i.e. "WorkspaceName;Owner" and consequently should be adapted!) and 'collection' data to use it in the `tf.exe workspaces /format:detailed` command, like that:

```
tf.exe" workspaces /format:detailed /collection:"https://tfs.yourtfs.com/tfs/defaultcollection" "NameOfYourWorkspace;John Doe"
```

The command output something like that:

```
===============================================
Workspace  : NameOfYourWorkspace
Owner      : John Doe
Computer   : YOU_COMPUTER
Comment    :
Collection : yourtfs.com\DefaultCollection
Permissions: Private
Location   : Local
File Time  : Current

Working folders:
 $/: C:\your\path
```

The important data that I want here is `Location   : Local` (or `Server`)

I have written a little powershell script, if it could be of little use for someone to extract the data in the output to use them:

```
function ExtractData($text, $key)
{
    $pattern = "^$key *: *(.+)$"
    $filteredText= $text | Select-String $key
    $found = $filteredText -match $pattern
    if ($found) {
        return $matches[1]
    }
    exit 1
}

$currentWorkspaceData = (& "$env:VS120COMNTOOLS..\IDE\tf.exe" workfold .)
$workspace = ExtractData $currentWorkspaceData "Workspace"
$found = $workspace -match "^(.+) \((.+)\)$"
if (!$found) {
    exit 1
}
$workspace = $matches[1] + ";" + $matches[2]

$collection = ExtractData $currentWorkspaceData "Collection"

$location=(ExtractData (& "$env:VS120COMNTOOLS..\IDE\tf.exe" workspaces /format:detailed /collection:$collection $workspace) "Location")
$localServer = $location -eq "Local"
if($localServer)
{
    Write-Host "Local!!!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Server!!!"
}
```

This script give the answer only for the current folder but could be easily adapted...